# objective C making UITextField for vc1 become UILabel vc2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to get my UITextField email in my first view controller to become the UILabel in my next view controller. It says there is an error stating there is no visible @interface for NSString declares the selector initvalue. I thought the interface was being loaded from the vc1.h file when you imported it on the vc2? any help would be nice. Heres what I have so far:

**vc1.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface loginUserViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, retain, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *login;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *registerBtn;


-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender;





@end
```

**vc2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "loginUserViewController.h"


@interface Home : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *Nav;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *logout;


-(IBAction)logout:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)bandHome:(id)sender;

@end
```

**vc2.m**

```
import "Home.h"
#import "loginUserViewController.h"


@interface Home ()

@end

@implementation Home
@synthesize username, band1, band2, band3;

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    loginUserViewController *object = [[loginUserViewController alloc]init];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[object.email.text initValue]];

    username.text = string;
}
```

vc1.m

```
#import "loginUserViewController.h"
#import "Home.h"
#import "createBandViewController.h"

@interface loginUserViewController ()


@end

@implementation loginUserViewController

@synthesize email, password;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
- (void)viewDidload
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [self setEmail:nil];
    [self setPassword:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
    if ([email.text isEqualToString:@""] || [password.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Please Fill all the field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Use integerValue or intValue instead of initValue

Comment: y r u using retain  @property (nonatomic, retain, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;. any specific reason

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace this string:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[object.email.text initValue]];
```

with this string:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[object.email.text intValue]];
```

and if you want simply the email just as a string then replace it with this string

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",object.email.text];
```

your error will be resolved.Hope it helps :)

Comment: It did resolve my error but the email text is still not displaying in my UIlabel on my Home view controller.

Comment: it returns 0 instead of the email

Comment: if you just want the email then please check my edited answer

Comment: For some reason it display null now when I switched it to "%@" instead of 0 or the email.

Comment: try after adding @synthesize in vc1.m file

Answer (score 0):

First of All in VC2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "loginUserViewController.h"


@interface Home : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *username; // Keep property strong to get the value
```

in VC2.m

```
@synthesize username;
```

Now in VC1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "homeviewcontroller.h"

@interface loginUserViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property (nonatomic) nsstring *username;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    username= self.email.text;
    homeviewcontroller *object = [[homeviewcontroller alloc]init];
     object.username.text=username;

   }
```